Boost converter ground to ground noise issue
I’ve been working on a boost converter with all the control circuitries being controlled by a microcontroller. I am facing a huge problem of noise on the ground. I have all the grounds common and when I see the voltage on oscilloscope between the input mains grounds and other ground traces the noise increases gradually with the distance from main ground. The problem gets worse when these spikes disturb my microcontroller ground, and I get spikes on all the pins of my microcontroller. Even when I am using a DAC, I can see the spikes on it. My connector isn't much far from the mains input but still I am getting a lot of noise with such a small distance.
The point I put probes on are shown:


I know Vero board setup is very noisy, but I need to do some testing before ordering my PCB. Is there any way I can handle this issue because the spikes go up to +-3 V. I don't know if there is some isolation technique because I need reference signals and other feedback in Real time from the converter so I can isolate every signal and making ground common was simpler, but I am getting this issue. This had already damaged one microcontroller, so I need a solution to handle this. Kindly help me solve this problem.

Sharing your schematic would help us answer. Also point out exactly where you probed when you measured the noise.

"We need a schematic" was even part of the answer you posted to your previous question.

@ThePhoton I have shown a few points where I put the probbes on.

Veroboard = no ground plane = noise. But show your measurement setup.

Right, as @winny says no groundplane is one issue.  The other is that it's very difficult to measure noise between two "grounds" with a long ground clip on a scope probe.  You're probably also measuring lots of EMI.

@JohnD I need something so that my microntroller is protected and its ground doesnt fluctuate because it effects the other periphrals and pins.

@kam1212 What you need is a properly designed PCB for your circuit, preferably 4-layered.

Consider the effect of stray inductance along the path indicated:

A typical/ballpark figure is 5nH per mm of wire length, perhaps higher in this case as the distance to nearby conductors is much higher.
This project spans at least several questions, as I recall; perhaps you have been told that ground plane design is a high priority (some would say "mandatory"*)  This illustrates why.
*"Mandatory" is strictly too strong a word, it certainly isn't mandatory and there are zillions of exceptions out there in the world.  But, more to the point: the exceptions aren't important for a beginner.
A solid plane has much less inductance than a long wire, and in particular a plane serves as a reference plane, against which we can measure nearby voltages.  The traces above the plane, then, have ca. 5nH/mm stray inductance along them, and the Q1-D1-C2 loop can be made very small (a few cm around -- component lead lengths included!), minimizing the inductance in that area.
Instead of using veroboard, copper-clad can be used, with pads formed either by cutting them out from the bulk, or by gluing or soldering pads on top.  This keeps connections low to the plane, and gives a well-connected ground behind everything.  An example from my proto box:
 
From: Deadbug_HV.jpg | Seven Transistor Labs (links to my site)
Small chits of copper-clad have been cut out and soldered down, to make isolated pads (they aren't easy to see in this top-down view, though).  Ground connections are simply soldered down directly.  Some connections are lazily made, simply floating in space between components; a prototype doesn't have to be robust, just work well enough.
This is an example of cut-out pads:
 
From: GD9.jpg | Seven Transistor Labs (links to my site)
I use a utility blade to score into the top layer of copper, all around a pad; the backside is then used as ground plane, using vias to bring it up to the surface where required (a hole is drilled, then copper wire soldered into the hole on both sides).  This allows the construction of very low (short height above GND plane --> even less stray inductance) and wide connections (wide traces/pours also reduces stray inductance), excellent for SMPS construction at high frequencies.  This particular circuit was a discrete gate driver, operating at up to 2MHz, and driving 5A or so into the load with less than 10ns rise/fall time.

Right Ill try to move the setup to the copper board
